# Show that particle whose position satisfies $\frac{d \mathbf{r}}{dt}= \mathbf{c} \times \mathbf{r}$ moves in a circular path with constant speed

Tags: multivariable-calculus, classical-mechanics

> A particle P moves so that its position vector **r** at time $t$ satisfies the differential equation
>
> $$\frac{d \mathbf{r}}{dt}= \mathbf{c} \times \mathbf{r},$$
>
> where **c** is a constant vector. Show that P moves with constant speed on a circular patch.

taking the dot product on the left with **c**, then using cyclic permutation we obtain;

$$ \mathbf{c} \cdot \frac{d \mathbf{r}}{dt} = \mathbf{c} \cdot \mathbf{c} \times \mathbf{r} = 0$$

similarly with **r**

$$ \mathbf{r} \cdot \frac{d \mathbf{r}}{dt} =  \mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{c} \times \mathbf{r} = 0 $$

At this point I did not know where to turn, so I consulted the solution manual.

in the solution manual it says that the above equation $ \mathbf{r} \cdot \frac{d \mathbf{r} }{dt} $ can be integrated to give $  \mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{r} = R^2 $.

I cant quite see how.

Comment: Please see this guide on typesetting math in your questions. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: And please don't shout at the readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With summation implied,
$$
r \cdot \frac{dr}{dt} = 0 \\
\Rightarrow r_i \frac{dr_i}{dt} = 0 \\
\Rightarrow 2 r_i \frac{dr_i}{dt} = 0 \\
\Rightarrow \frac{d}{dt}(r_i r_i) = 0 \\
\Rightarrow r.r = k^2
$$

The constant must be positive because of the property of the dot product that $r.r \geq 0$, and equality is attained only when $r=0$.

ETA: You don't really need coordinates for this, it is pretty much obvious when you see $r \cdot \frac{dr}{dt}=0$ and recall $r=r(t)$ only.